# Suggestions on how to compute $\int d^3 u \frac{1}{u}\exp(-(\textbf{w}-\textbf{u})^2/c^2)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I was looking for which coordinates and change of variables would make the integration of  $\int d^3 u \frac{1}{u}\exp(-(\textbf{w}-\textbf{u})^2/c^2)$ the easiest. Note that the bold faced values are vectors and that $u=\sqrt{\textbf{u }\cdot \textbf{u}}$ and c is a constant. I was thinking that maybe a shift in the coordinates so that the exponential has a single vector could be a good idea because it would be symmetric around zero. Any suggestions on an approach would be great.

Comment: What is $d^3 u /u?$ Why is it not $d^3?$ And what are you integrating with respect to? And over what space?

Comment: Do you mean $|w-u|^2$?

Comment: @IgorRivin $d^3u$ stands for $du_1 du_2 du_3$.

Comment: @EricAuld In an alternate universe? I have never seen this...

Comment: What eric said is correct.

Comment: No absolute values? What is the square of a vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

substitute $x = u-w,$ and you will get the integral of $\exp(-|x|^2)/|x+w|.$ To do that, polar coordinates are your friends.

Comment: what about when w=x? I have the integral as $4\pi \int_0^\infty dx \frac{x^2}{x-w}\exp(-x^2/c^2)$

Comment: or have I made a mistake?

Comment: @B_Scheiner I made a typo, now fixed.

Comment: but when you shift the coordinates you should have exp(-x^2)/(x+w) since you have u=x+w

Comment: @B_Scheiner yes, very true, I fixed the typo, but the suggestion still stands.